# Finding the dual basis after a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$, $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and let $T$ be an isomorphism between them. Given basis $\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ for $V$ with dual basis $\{\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n\}$ for $V^*$, we know that $\{T(b_1), \dots, T(b_n) \}$ is a basis for $W$. However, is it possible to find a basis for $W^*$ in terms of the previously defined quantities?

(also, would it make a difference if $V$,$W$ are subspaces of a shared vector space?)

Comment: the dual map of $T$, denoted by $T^*$, goes from $W^*$ to $V^*$ and its invertible. If $V$ and $W$ are real-valued vector spaces then the matrix representation of $T^*$ is given by the transpose of the matrix representation of $T$, both given in terms of the basis and the dual basis. Then you are interested in the map $(T^{-1})^\top:V^*\to W^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that

$\theta_i(b_j)=\delta_{ij }$

and you want to find a basis $\{\phi_1, \dots, \phi_n\} \in W^*$ such that

$\phi_i(T(b_j))=\delta_{ij }= \theta_i(b_j)$

This tells you that

$\phi_i T= \theta_i$

I’ll let you take it from there.